# Boolean search on two columns Python

Tags: python, pandas, function, apply

I have a dataframe `all_articles` with the columns `['title', 'astract']`.
I have written a function to do a boolean search on one column:

```
def searchString(string):
    if ((('apple' or 'banana') and ('fork' or 'knife') and ('red' or 'green'))) in string:
        return True
    return False
```

Now, I want to create a column that contains true if *the combination* of the `title` or `abstract` fulfills the requirement of my boolean search. As an example, suppose that my dataframe looks as follows:

```
title                 abstract       
'apple'               'red fork'          
'orange'              'apple red fork'          
'knife banana red'    'green bowl'
```

Then, I wish my function returns: `['True','True','False']`.

My current apply command looks as follows:

```
all_articles['boolean'] = all_articles['Abstract'].astype(str).apply(searchString)
```

Obviously, I could create a column in which I merge `title` and `abstract` and apply the function on that column. However, I am curious if there are ways to do this through an apply function that has 2 columns of input.

Comment: You should really test that `searchString` function; it won't do what you want. But if you want to apply something to several columns, `DataFrame.apply` already can operate on an entire row of a `DataFrame`. You'd just need to modify your function to take in a row instead of a single string.

Comment: It would be much better let alone performance-wise to use `np.where()` or a vectorized solution.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy, the function does work well on one column containing multiple strings. However, I would like to apply the function in a way that it looks whether my criteria are met on the merged string from `title` and `abstract` without having to actually merge them.

Comment: @CeliusStingher, how could I use the np.where() function in this context? I looked at the documentation but cannot think of a way to successfully implement it.

Comment: You are aware that `(('apple' or 'banana') and ('fork' or 'knife') and ('red' or 'green'))` is just `red`, aren't you.

Comment: No I am not, why is that the case?

Comment: I just asked another question specifically focused on my function. Can you answer there? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60342027/boolean-search-function-returns-false-instead-of-true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your clause, the result should be `[False, True, True]` and this is how you get it:

```
df.stack().str.contains('(?=.*(apple|banana))(?=.*(fork|knife))(?=.*(red|green))').unstack().any(1)
```